# Git: Make Pull Request with Current Changes (not knowing history)

Tags: git

I made a feature branch off of master and got my code working locally.  I've made a series of commits and then a pull request.  The SHAs of the commits in the pull request don't line up with what I see locally using `git log`.

So I want to make a new pull request that just takes the diff between master and my feature branch as it currently is.

How would I do that?

I suppose I could copy my local repo into a new directory and somehow link it to the remote repo.  Then running `git commit` should commit the differences between the two repos?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- fetch the PR branch

  ```
  git fetch origin pull/37/head:pr37
  ```

(replace 37 by the PR id)

- create a branch and make a commit with your current branch content

  ```
  git checkout -b newpr pr37
  git reset --hard master # assuming the right content is on master
  git reset --soft @{-1}
  git commit -m "new diff commit"
  git push -u origin newpr
  ```